# Adding attachments in java mail API android

Tags: java, android, email

I can send email by this code and email is send successfully
but the problem is that i want to attach picture to my email.

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myemailaddress@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(reciep));
            message.setSubject(subjct);
            message.setContent(txtmsg,"text/html; charset=utf-8");
            Transport.send(message);
```

Below is the method from which i can take picture and save it in myfolder.

```
private void saveImage(byte[] arg0) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.MeraFolder";

    File myDir = new File(root);
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String fname = timeStamp + ".jpg";

    file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);
    FileOutputStream out;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now i have 2 questions

1. Is there a way that i can attach the recently taken picture in my
   email or is there any way that the picture i take is directly
   attached too my email
2. When there is no internet connectivity the email gets failed ow can
   i over come this problem that when there is no internet connectivity
   the email gets on hold as soon as internet connectivity is available
   the email is sent

Any help will be appreciated as i am new to android